# Error RPC ERROR 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations, how to solve this error

Tags: permissions, wallet, rpc

1.abi_json_to_bin
[image]

2.unlock default wallet

3.get public_key lists,"EOS5CMpK8wH5MzFA3Vptb3RizKr5MLmEF7A4K9FhL4HSyVrVRT7o8" is one of them
[image]

4.make sure the public_key is related to the account "mytoken"
[image]

5.get-info,the latest head_block_num is 125258
[image]

6.get_block ,the ref_block_prefix of the block is 1750215734,and the timestamp is 2019-12-05T12:20:53.000
[image]

7.get_required_keys,it matched
[image]

8.sign_transaction,the signatures is "SIG_K1_K4p7eKRPY29QT9BcExgM1xz1gBBfziiMPhhGTUpfv49jhhkHcBQciF6cp3mo3gAc2QLJqy5LujN8wPy65U7UoqmRZWGnNp"
[image]

9.push_action,then there is a problem
[image]

can anyone give me a hand?I would really appreiciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First, kill your Keosd process. And try again.

If you get same Error, you would try comparing with root account and without root account.

Comment: I create a tested account and there is no difference.

Comment: Signature Key made by chain_ID, context_free_data and Public_key. And push_transaction function in controller.cpp would recover the signature Key.
I think one of these data is wrong. I want to recommend debuging programs